# Redmine error after migrating to new version

Tags: ruby, docker, redmine

I wanted to migrate from old Redmine version 3.1 to latest one. I installed redmine with plugins which I use, everything worked.

Then I imported database from old Redmine version, but when I click on task, od project, I am geting this error.

Since I am not Ruby programmer, wanted to ask what this means and if there is possibility to fix?

```
  Rendered projects/show.html.erb within layouts/base (7.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 153ms (ActiveRecord: 114.7ms)
  
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `description' for #<Tracker:0x00000000076ad540>):
    65:       <% @trackers.each do |tracker| %>
    66:         <tr>
    67:           <td class="name">
    68:             <%= link_to tracker.name, project_issues_path(@project, :set_filter => 1, :tracker_id => tracker.id), :title => tracker.description %>
    69:           </td>
    70:           <td>
    71:             <%= link_to @open_issues_by_tracker[tracker].to_i, project_issues_path(@project, :set_filter => 1, :tracker_id => tracker.id) %>
  
app/views/projects/show.html.erb:68:in `block in _app_views_projects_show_html_erb__4349052137991159230_63703440'
app/views/projects/show.html.erb:65:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__4349052137991159230_63703440'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:65:in `sudo_mode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When upgrading your Redmine version, you need to update the database schema for the new version. This is called migrating the database.

With a common configuration, you should thus run the following commands after an upgrade while inside the main Redmine directory:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production 
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Please see the [Redmine Upgrade guide](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade#Step-4-Update-the-database) for more details on how to upgrade Redmine.